# Possible risks on running both Apache (httpd) and Tomcat together on Godaddy VPS?

Tags: java, php, apache, tomcat, vps

I'm not a server expert nor a Java dev. I tried asking the support at Godaddy and searching on Google, but no luck finding what I need.

### **Background**

My company's VPS (production server) on Godaddy hosts many websites with Apache using WHM. One of our apps that recently developed by our new team requires Tomcat on our production server for one of our clients (we usually create an individual cPanel via WHM to manage each client's website).

Godaddy only told us that we can install Tomcat via EasyApache globally, but we will use it on our own risk. They would not answer me what the risks are.

### **Questions**

1. What are the possible risks for running both Apache and Tomcat on
   our production server?
2. Will Tomcat affect the other websites on the VPS?
3. Is it possible to just run Tomcat under one of the domains on
   our VPS?

Comment: 1. Your's. As in, not our's. 2. Yes. 3. Purchase a separate (and independent) VPS from a different vendor.

Comment: high risk running *anything* on Godaddy as they are a terrible host.

Comment: @Dagon To be fair, they have low prices and good advertising. Presumably the iron triangle strikes again...

Comment: Intersecting topic, but not appropriate to Stack Overflow.